# How do I get value from ArrayOfString in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a client application in VB.Net that calls webservice which returns ArrayOfString. How do I get value of strings in VB.Net

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>Initial</string>
  <string>Progress</string>
  <string>Complete</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Comment: Either the web service returns an object that is likely either `String()` or `List(Of String)` so you treat it like you would any other array or collection, or else it actually returns that XML code and you read it like any other XML. Either way, it's not for us to just do it for you or teach you how from scratchy. It's for you to do reasonable research and make a reasonable attempt and then post here with a specific question if and when you encounter an actual issue.

Comment: What you've shown is XML. How did you set it up to use the webservice - did you go through the Solution Explorer pane to Add -> Service Reference?